# Document generation with Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a need to generate project specific documents which follow the exact same format. The only difference is specifics such as the end user, point of contact, site location, lead engineer, project manager ect.

In LaTeX I would create a .tex file and declare all of these as variables. Then all the template files would look at this .tex file, and when compiled gives .pdf files with the customer information. Then all I need to do is edit the text file with the variables, and run a script to create the project documentation.

I would like to be able to do the same thing in Word, but I can't work out how to do this. I need the solution to be as simple as fill in these fields, run this script and the project documents are generated. I ideally don't want to have to make changes to each document as this takes a lot of time, and people will skip documents because "its not important".

If I can also include or exclude sections of content based on some flags, that would be ideal.

For context, a lot of this documentation is somewhat useless, and we could happily have an SOP replace the lot. Its real use however is to keep the auditors from using us to prove that they are doing stuff. By having the documentation, it makes them approve how we are working. If they want to change stuff for the sake of it, they have to put it in writing, and few people are stupid enough to request pointless BS in writing. Also we can beat them with the change order($$$$$) if its truely stupid.

Comment: If you are familiar with programming, that should be pretty easy to acomplish with any programming/scripting language that's able to utilise "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" .NET API. You create Word template, designate bookmarks as placeholders for data and populate them with help of .NET API and some programming/scripting language(VBS ,C#, other..)

Comment: I mostly deal with PLC/SCADA programming which is bits and bytes, not really API or .NET stuff. I don't know how to get started with that.